# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and Radeon 6700xt driver crash when opening games through Steam or Lutris

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have installed a Radeon RX 6700XT video card in my computer. Normal operation is fine, I can surf the web, watch videos through VLC, open office docs, etc.

When I launch any game through Steam there is a flicker and the screen stops responding to input. The mouse moves but you cannot click on anything. I can change sesions by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and reboot the box but I have not found a way to recover the intial session without rebooting. I have also been unsuccesful in finding a log or something that will indicate what is causing what I am assuming is a driver crash.

When I change sessions and login I am presented with `[drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!` repeating as many times as I want to watch it print.

Things I have tried:

- Changing video drivers, I have not found a way to do this with AMD.
- Re-installed Steam.
- Logged into Ubuntu without Cinnamon running, this produced the same result.
- Installed Lutris and tried to launch a game, same result.

Graphics:

```
  Device-1: AMD Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT / 6800M] vendor: XFX
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 ports:
    active: DP-1,DP-3,HDMI-A-1 empty: DP-2 bus-ID: 06:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:73df
    class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
System:
  Kernel: 6.1.0-1008-oem x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 tk: GTK 3.24.33 vt: 2 dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
```

Any ideas how to resolve or troubleshoot this?

Comment: I would start at the Steam Support site as the problem is with that environment.

Comment: It also happens with games launched with Lutris not just Steam.

Comment: Then contact them.